# Per app proxy/'port forwarding'(iOS or Android)

Tags: android, ios, firewall, portforwarding

Is it possible to proxy/'port forward' any app traffic on a per app bases? 
The bottom line is to be able to assign an IP address for each app where IP traffic will pass through.

I heard iOS has a shadowsocks app when jail broken and there are per-app vpn apps but I doubt it's a viable able to achieve this... Is there anything like this on Android/iOS?

Generally speaking are iOS and Android designed in a way to make this a possibility??

Answer (score 0):

If you look on the Market there are tons of apps out there obviously many claim to do it and only a handful actually do do it. Going down the list of a few

1. Orbot
2. Cloud Vpn
3. openVpn

Comment: Checked all three apps online but can't figure out if any of them allow a separate proxy address for each separate app. That's the main goal behind the question.